# How to log into FTP when there is a special character in the username?

Tags: ftp, passwords, special-characters

I have login credentials for an FTP server that are in this form:

User: name@domain.com
Pass: alpha-numberic-password

When attempting to log in, it will not work because of the @ special character. I have tried the %40 trick and the %64 trick and neither worked.

I am trying with FileZilla and [this is the only relevant info](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=765) I found on their forums.

I can get it to work with CuteFTP 8 Home, but that is quite old and I would like to use a different client in the future.

Is there a general setting for this kind of thing that allows `@` in the username? Is there a more expansive client that can utilize these credentials?

---

I realize that `@` should not be in the username or password, but that is outside of my control, and people do still do it like this sometimes.

Comment: If you are using FileZilla, then can't you just enter your username and password and enter the domain in a different textbox?

Comment: @TylerH I don't understand your question. Yes, I put the domain in one box, the user in another, and the pass in a third.

Comment: @TylerH [The interface looks like this.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oX7zu.png) Red is the domain, blue is the user, and black is the pass. Obviously, this is a blank one so you don't see my actual info.

Comment: So where are you inputting an @ symbol? Isn't that what the problem was? You should only be putting your username (**not** followed by the @ symbol and/or domain) in the username field.

Comment: @TylerH You don't understand. The username is `name@domain.com`. That is the full username and this is what does work in cuteFTP.

Comment: As far as I know, FileZilla does not support the @ symbol (or various other special characters) in usernames. Contact the sysadmin and ask them to have the username changed.

Comment: @TylerH Yeah, that's what I've done, but they take their dandy time.

Comment: I do think browsers support @ symbols in usernames if you simply must connect and CuteFTP isn't an option. Use `ftp://username:password@domain.com/` or `ftp://username:password@ipaddress/`. But note that you'll have to use \40 instead of the @ symbol in the username.

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try replacing `@` with `%40`

Answer (score 1):

According to the RFC for FTP (RFC959) a @ in the username is perfectly acceptable ("any of the 128 ASCII characters except <CR> and <LF>"). FTP has also no encoding/escaping of characters. So if it works with CuteFTP and not with FileZilla it might be a bug there. I don't know what FileZilla does with the @ character but maybe a tcpdump/wireshark would help to find out.

Comment: I believe if you enter "user@domain" into the username box FileZilla automatically tries to decompose it based on the @ and connect. If you enter a username which contains an @ in the username box AND a domain in the domain box, then the "feature" goes haywire. I guess technically this makes FileZilla not standard-compliant?